# AJAX web applications with no hand-written JavaScript

Tags: c#, java, javascript, python

I'm looking for solutions that make it possible to create AJAX-enabled web applications without need to write JavaScript code manually. The requirements are:

1. Performance doesn't matter. It can be slow, JavaScript may be unoptimized, amount of code it generates may be large.
2. Platform doesn't matter as long as I can work with it on either Linux or Windows.
3. Language doesn't matter as long as it's Python, Java or C#.
4. I want to be able to create composite 'widgets' that can be updated dynamically using AJAX. For instance, I want to be able to load data dynamically and replace existing controls with the other ones when user clicks the button on that page.
5. As long as this solution provides concepts like 'Panel' (composite widget), 'EditBox' and 'Label', I don't care if it's hard to create my own controls.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/hu-HU/webtoolkit/) is perfect for you.

Here is [why to choose GWT](http://keylimetie.com/blog/2009/3/11/why-choose-gwt/).

Answer (score 2):

I went with [JSF 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html) in combination with [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) to program my first website with AJAX. PrimeFaces is phenomenal and easy to use, no hand-written JavaScript necessary. They have a [Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) on their site.

Comment: haha, just checked their showcase. What I basically wanted to get is  in their Inplace editor demo. Thanks! Considering using it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you GWT from Google. It is great, well done framework that allows creating Web 2.0 applications without dealing with HTML/JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to treat JS as an intermediate language, (which CoffeeScript currently does), but on top of that, you want to transform the DOM into some completely different API.

Also, the point of web apps are that they, to a large extent, behave the same independent of platform...at least on desktop operating systems.

I think the closest thing you're going to get to python would include a mix of [CoffeeScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script) (whose syntax is similar to Python and Ruby in many ways) and a widget library, something like [JQuery UI](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui). (And I can't believe I just recommended those two things).

edit: Sorry, ninja editing my post.

Comment: The problem is, I'm already quite a 'mature' desktop/backend developer, so I just don't want to become a professional in Web. I only need it for PoC implementation of my idea, I'm not going to use it some other way.

Comment: Well, it is always possible to do both. If you ever do get more into frontend, I recommend learning javascript, it's a lot better than it looks, and the DOM is...not as bad once you abstract away browser inconsistencies.